# Problem with ruamel.yaml for installing another python package

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I want to install a package with this command: pip install git+https://github.com/BioSystemsUM/mewpy.git

It collects the package, but at the end it shows:

```
Installing collected packages: ruamel.yaml, pathos, matplotlib, boolean.py, jmetalpy, cobamp, mewpy
  Attempting uninstall: ruamel.yaml
    Found existing installation: ruamel-yaml 0.15.46
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'ruamel-yaml'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

I couldn't find a way to solve this issue and install this package. Any suggestion's very appreciated.

Comment: How did you create your virtualenv? You are not trying to install in the system environment (which may already have a ruamel.yaml installed) are you? What does `which pip` and `pip list` output (please add to your question.

Comment: Whether it is in the environment or not, I get the same error message. which pip doesn't work, but pip list results shows: ruamel-yaml                        0.15.46
ruamel.yaml                        0.16.12
ruamel.yaml.clib                   0.2.2

Comment: Problem solved with re-installing python